# window.open opens in new window instead of new tab when using "nofollow/sponsored"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, hyperlink

I have a window.open link that is expected to open a new tab, but somehow it opens a new window when i use "nofollow" on it.

This opens a new tab:

```
        $('.b_link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open('{{ $sponsored_product->website.' }}', '_blank', 'noopener');
    });
```

But this doesn't, it opens a new window.

```
        $('.b_link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open('{{ $sponsored_product->website.' }}', '_blank', 'noopener nofollow');
    });
```

Somehow the "nofollow" triggers the link to open in a new window instead of a new tab. Why is that? And how to fix it? I need the nofollow or "sponsored" on it.

Comment: I don't think `nofollow` on a window.open will do what you think it will do.  What do you think will happen by adding this?

Comment: Relevant: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#window_functionality_features

Comment: I don’t see how the code you have shown would work in the first place, `'{{ $sponsored_product->website.' }}'` looks like it should trigger a syntax error …?

Comment: @freedomn-m i think i get what you say. The nofollow is not possible there because it won't be reached by google anyways since it's not a html link?

Comment: @CBroe The syntax is correct, it's laravel.

Comment: @DappFuture something like `'{{ $foobar }}'` would make sense, but I don’t see how `'{{ $foobar.' }}'` could produce any sensible result, with the `.` and the uneven number of single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('.b_link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open('{{ $sponsored_product->website.' }}','noopener nofollow');
    });
```

Comment: This fixed it! So the nofollow triggers a _blank in a window.open or how can i understand this?

Comment: @DappFuture no, this did not fix it. You opened a window with the _name_ `noopener nofollow` now, instead of actually setting the window options `noopener` and `nofollow`.

Comment: @Dapp Future :The reason was when you entered "window.open" its already been routed to a new tab and then when you entered the   "_blank" it automatically routed to a new window ..

Comment: First i thought this fixed it, but from what other people said and some more research, it seems like nofollow can't be used in here, since the link is not reached by google in the window.open anyways. So only noopener is possible and needed?!